# Chrome OS - Installed PWA does not launch from host link using Android Intents (Deep Links)

Tags: android-intent, deep-linking, progressive-web-apps, google-chrome-os, manifest.json

The PWA documentation from Google states: "[If the user clicks on a link within an installed app to https://example.com/read, it would be caught by the intent and opened in the Progressive Web App.](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/integration/webapks#android_intent_filters)"

However, I've found that that is not the case. Links to my app clicked on from within Chrome or other apps like Gmail do not launch the installed PWA on Chrome OS. There does not appear to be another way that I can tell to [Deep Link](https://w3c.github.io/manifest/#deep-links) into an installed PWA. When installing my PWA, my manifest is this:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "short_name": "MyApp",
  "description": "MyApp is cool",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "icons": [
    ...
  ],
  "start_url": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/"
}
```

Does anyone know if it's possible? How are 3rd party OAuth redirects supposed to happen in a PWA?

UPDATE: I've found that Android does in fact capture the intent of an installed PWA and launches it rather than using the web browser, however the same does not happen in Chrome OS. Any idea when they plan on bringing this functionality to Chromebooks?

Comment: I'm also wondering with the same issue. What I got is, IOS browser does not support this feature.